# Invalid reference of Static Resource in LWC Salesforce

Tags: static-resources, lightning-web-components

I am trying to use Static resource inside the lightning web component. while importing getting this error:-  "Invalid reference SDFCImages of type resourceUrl in file StaticResourceDemo.js"

here how I import static resource in LWC.

StaticResourceDemo.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, } from 'lwc';                                                                                                                  
import SFDC_Images from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SDFCImages';  
export default class StaticResourcesDemo extends LightningElement {  
    Sfdcimage1 = SFDC_Images + '/images/1518.png';  
    Sfdcimage2 = SFDC_Images + '/images/Capture.png';  
    someCode="Static Resources";  
}
```

how my static resource looks like on Salesforce...[image]

Comment: anybody here to answer?

Comment: Are you sure that screenshot is from the same scratch org that you're trying to push to? Your code works for me but I do get that error if the static resource doesn't exist in the org yet.

Comment: @VaishaliGarg so what fixed it? Can you close your question if it's not valid?

Comment: @citizen I don't know. how to close question. please help me to close this one.

Comment: @VaishaliGarg Just answer it yourself with the fix that resolved it, so if someone else comes across this they might know why